# Как отобрать элемент, находящийся на странице в iframe?

Tags: jquery

На странице вставляется iframe c ютюба:

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/jZNeRQnjZic" frameborder="0">
```

Этот iframe содержит тэг embed. Нужно "дотянуться" до этого embed, чтобы добавить в него атрибут  wmode="opaque". Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в конец ссылки добавить параметр

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/jZNeRQnjZic?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0">
```

Вот так передается параметр для ютуб плеера, а выбрать элементы внутри фрейма нельзя

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо! :) А откуда знаете, что так атрибут в youtube можно передать?

Comment: Сталкивался с проблемой, когда видеоплеер перекрывал выпадающее меню во всех ие, так и узнал

Answer (score 0):

```
$("iframe").attr({wmode: "opaque"});
```

Или если нужно определённому фрейму добавить, то допишите ID

```
<iframe id="anime" width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/jZNeRQnjZic" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

И вот такой код

```
$("iframe #anime").attr({wmode: "opaque"});
```

Comment: Нет, не iframe надо атрибут добавить, а элементу содержащемуся в этом iframe. А iframe содержит целиком другую страницу с html-head-body и уже где-то в body находится embed (содержащий в данном случае флешовый ролик с youtube). И вот этому embed надо добавить атрибут wmode="opaque"